# Access Apache2 localhost on Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2, localhost

I am currently developing a website along with an android mobile application and I am using Genymotion to test the application but when running the application and it is trying to make a connection, it returns a connection refused error.

The same happens when I try to access the site from a browser within the virtual machine.

How can I resolve this and be able to access my site on http://localhost from the Virtual Machine?

Comment: This question ***is*** [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), as it can be answered with regard to "running third-party applications on Ubuntu" (i.e., Apache, the VM, and Genymotion) and "using and administering official Ubuntu flavors" (potentially a problem involving administering Apache to get things working).

Comment: A few things to check are whether Apache is set up to allow connections from other machines, what the LAN IP address of the Apache machine is, and whether that LAN IP address works from within the virtual machine.